# How to get property on relation in blade

Tags: php, laravel-5, view, relation

I'm getting the following error in my view when trying to access a property in a hasOne relationship inside a view, Am I not allowed to do this from the view, basically what I want to achieve is to have a dynamic select on properties that i can relate to the listing model.

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::$name (View: C:\wamp64\www\grupoeverest\resources\views\admin\listing\property.blade.php)
```

PropertyType model

```
class PropertyType extends Model
{
    protected $table = "property_types";
    protected $fillable= ['name'];
    public function property()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Property');
    }
}
```

Property model

```
class Property extends Model
{
    protected $table="properties";
    protected $fillable=['value'];

    public function propertyType(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\PropertyType');
   }
    public function listing(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Listing');
   }
 }
```

Listing model

```
class Listing extends Model
{

    protected $table="listings";
    protected $fillable=['name','price','squaremeters','number',
        'street','neighbourhood','description','description',
        'zipcode','longitude','latitude', 
        'listing_type_id','operation_type_id' ];
    public function listingType(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\ListingType', 'id');
    }
    public function pictures(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Picture', 'listing_id');
    }
    public function properties(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Property', 'listing_id');
    }

 }
```

Controller action

```
    public function properties($id)
    {

        return view('admin.listing.property',[
            'listing' => Listing::find($id),
            'types' => ListingType::all(),
        ]);
    }
```

view

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <h4>here
  </h4>

  @foreach($listing->properties as $property)
  <h4> {{$property->value}}{{$property->propertyType()->name}}
  </h4>

  @endforeach
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `$property->propertyType->name`

Comment: but propertyType is a method, wouldn't that try to look for an attribute named propertyType?

Comment: your answer was correct to the point of the view, my main issue fixed changing the relationships for Property and PropertyType

Comment: @JulioVillalba yep its a method so un-intuitive a little bit, but its a part of laravel's many short cuts

Answer (score 0):

my issues fixed by changing PropertyType method property to hasMany and Property method PropertyType to belongsTo, and using the answer provided by Abdullah in my view, which does make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

For Example

```
protected $table = 'states';

public function City() {    
    return $this->hasMany(City::class);
}
```

}

```
public function Farm() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Farm','farm_id','id');
}
```

**Further Information visit**      https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships